# How to prevent adding a duplicate object value of arraylist?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a problem to prevent adding new object to array which has the same value of id like existing element of object in array.
My array is like this:

```
var arr = [
       {id:1, name:'Fabricio'},
       {id:2, name:'Leontina'},
       {id:3, name:'Rodrigo'}];
```

If I want to add object like this `{id:2; name:'Evander'}`, that couldn't be done because of id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check if an id is in the array as:

```
if(!arr.some(el => el.id === 2))
  arr.push({ id: 2, name: "Evander" });
```

But actually this is a good usecase for a Map:

```
const users = new Map([
 [1, { name: "one" }],
 [2, { name: "two" }]
]);
```

So you can easily check if an id is already there in constant time:

```
if(!users.has(2))
  users.set(2, { name: "newtwo" });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @opie de nada! :)

Comment: You could also keep the id inside the object, assuming it has some value outside being a primary key: `const users = new Map( arr.map( o => [o.id, o] ) )`.  With thanks to @JonasW. for the reminder about `map`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const arr = [
       {id:1, name:'Fabricio'},
       {id:2, name:'Leontina'},
       {id:3, name:'Rodrigo'}
];

function push(array, item) {
  if (!array.find(({id}) => id === item.id)) {
    array.push(item);
  }
}

push(arr, {id: 2, name: 'Evander'}); // won't be added
push(arr, {id: 10, name: 'Kyle'}); // will be added
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `array.filter` function in the following way:

```js
let array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Fabricio' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Leontina' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Rodrigo' }
]

function add (object) {
  if (object) {
    if (array.filter(x => x.id === object.id).length === 0) {
      array.push(object)
    }
  }
}

add({ id: 2, name: 'Evander' }) // won't add
add({ id: 4, name: 'Evander' }) // will add

console.log(array)
```